# wx.BitmapButton incorrect size?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I can't seem to figure out why my bitmap button looks like a standard button with the image in the middle. I've followed the examples and the wxPython constructor methods and nothing seems to change or match what I see in the examples and tutorials. Here is my constructor:

```
    bmp = wx.Bitmap("plus-circle.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
    self.imgButton = wx.BitmapButton(self, bitmap=bmp)
    self.imgButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.addCategory)
    catSizer.Add(self.txtCategory, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
    catSizer.Add(self.cmbCategory, 1, wx.ALL, 5)
    catSizer.Add(self.imgButton, 2, wx.ALL, 5)
```

And this is how it is shown in my 'panel' as it's part of a tabbed window:

[Image of Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLUug.png)

How can I just have the image as my button without all the extra border around it? I did try the GetHeight, GetWidth, methods, plus DefaultSize, etc, but nothing seems two work.

I'm running Python 3.6 on Mac OS Mojave.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the button to the sizer, you are instructing it to change the proportion to 2.
`catSizer.Add(self.imgButton, 2, wx.ALL, 5)`

`Sizer.Add(window, proportion=0, flag=0, border=0, userData=None)`

`proportion` -

> this parameter is used in wx.BoxSizer to indicate if a child of a
>   sizer can change its size in the main orientation of the wx.BoxSizer -
>   where 0 stands for not changeable and a value of more than zero is
>   interpreted relative to the value of other children of the same
>   wx.BoxSizer. For example, you might have a horizontal wx.BoxSizer with
>   three children, two of which are supposed to change their size with
>   the sizer. Then the two stretchable windows would get a value of 1
>   each to make them grow and shrink equally with the sizer’s horizontal
>   dimension.

Change your code to the following:
`catSizer.Add(self.imgButton, 0, wx.ALL, 5)`
that should fix your problem.

Comment: Boy do I feel dumb lol. I assumed the numbers meant position within the box sizer. So if i had 4 items, 0, 1, 2, 3 was the order I wanted them placed. Oops, but thanks, made the change and now it works as expected.

Comment: @YYC_Code Don't be too hard on yourself, sizers can drive you nuts, even when you have been using them for ages.